# (SCSS) How to import mixins that uses component's props?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, scss-mixins

Currently, I have a mixin being used for a component below:

```
// Card/styles.scss
@mixin spacing($property, $max, $space) {
  @for $i from 1 to $max + 1 {
    &#{$i}x {
      #{$property}: $i * $space;
    }
  }
}

.Card {

...

  &--margin-bottom- {
    @include spacing(margin-bottom, 7, 4px);
  }
}
```

I tried creating a utils file so I can import it using `@use`,

```
// utils.scss
@mixin spacing($property, $max, $space) {
  @for $i from 1 to $max + 1 {
    &#{$i}x {
      #{$property}: $i * $space;
    }
  }
}
```

and importing is via:

```
// Card/styles.scss
@use '../utils' as utils;

.Card {

...

  &--margin-bottom- {
    @include utils.spacing(margin-bottom, 7, 4px);
  }
}
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):    
@include utils.spacing; 
Invalid CSS after "@include utils": expected "}", was ".spacing;"in /Users/_MY
FOLDER_/Documents/GITHUB/src/components/Card/styles.scss
```

My question is, how do I create a utility mixin so I can use this in other components?